# iPhone webview - chroma keying possible? (how can I make a color transparent)

Tags: iphone, webview, transparent

I have an iPhone app that has to show web content on top of it.(an webview on top)
Normally I would make the webview transparent and then I simply see what is beneath. That is ok, but not entirely.

I would like to be able to set a Chroma Key = a color that the webview will make transparent so that I see my app beneath.

Is this even possible in iPhone webviews? Thanks,
Neal

Comment: Maybe it is possible to mask a color in UIWebView